# Header should be included once

Tags: c++, header-files

In header files I've seen two main ways for defining macro to avoid including the file more than once.

1.

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS
#define SOME_CLASS
//code ...
#endif
```

2.

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS
//code...
#define SOME_CLASS
#endif
```

Which is more preferable and why?

Comment: There is also third method #pragma once. It is not standardized, but works for most compilers.

Comment: personally, if the compiler set supports it, I would use `#pragma once`

Comment: #pragma once is convenient and I wish it was standardized, but I have to prefer the methods listed above.  They are kludgy, but portable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I prefer the first method, because it doesn't matter what happens after the ifndef because it will be defined straight after.

Comment: If //code happens to #include something else which then re-includes this file you'll get stuck whilst the first way doesn't have a problem with that.

Comment: Aye, that could be a big problem.

Answer (score 4):

The first option is commonly optimized by compilers to behave like the non-standard `#pragma once`.

It is also safer in case of recursive includes. If, in the `//code...` part, you include another header which includes .... which includes the header you're currently editing, then the second version won't work.

Comment: +1 The possible recursive include is the key why the first should be used.

Comment: true, I should probably have mentioned that first. Oh well

Comment: Is the optimization comment really true? Do you know which compilers specifically recognize pattern in the pre-processor?

Comment: @Rob: I know MSVC does, and to be honest, I believe it is fairly common. It is such an obvious pattern to optimize for, after all.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for the first one.

Reason: If you ever want to change the guard name (say, `SOME_CLASS` to `SOMECLASS`), you don't have to scroll all the way down to the end of file to change it too.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use `#pragma once`. With `#define` you must be very careful when using multiple libraries as the guard name may not be unique.

Comment: Not all C++ compilers support `#pragma once`, so this is probably not the best option if you want portability.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Name one production-quality compiler that doesn't support `#pragma once`.

Comment: @John: While GCC has implemented `#pragma once`, it has [declared its usage "obsolete"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/cpp/Obsolete-once_002donly-headers.html#Obsolete-once_002donly-headers).

Comment: @Johnsyweb: it says that `#import` is obsolete, not `#pragma once`. And believe me that GCC supports a way more "obsolete" features ;)

Comment: @John: ...for some value of "supports" ;-) It does say, "Neither one is as portable as a wrapper `#ifndef`, and we recommend you do not use them in new programs."

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I guess we have at least several End of The Worlds until GCC stops supporting it. I mean, really, there is a lot more other extensions C++ codebases uses than `#pragma once`. And `#pragma once` is much better than 3 duplicates of `#define _CONFIG_H`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first option. Suppose you include more files, and these files in turn include the file containing `#ifndef SOME_CLASS`.

I think it's fairly easy to spot include errors, if the `#define SOME_CLASS` isn't adjacent to `#ifndef SOME_CLASS`.

```
// SomeClass.h
#ifndef SOME_CLASS
#include "OtherFile.h" // will eventually lead to #include "SomeClass.h"
#define SOME_CLASS

... boat load of code here...

#endif // SOME_CLASS
```